# HttpContext.current.Session returns Nothing

Tags: asp.net

I access some session variables from within a class library, the properties/methods are being called from a ASP.NET page. But the Session returns nothing why would this be?

Comment: At which point are you trying to access the HttpContext.Session object?

Comment: on load, there only difference on this page is that it has a custom base page this in turn inherits from Page

Comment: This forum has a solution that you might want to consider: http://forums.asp.net/t/998446.aspx/1?Using+HttpContext+from+class+library

Answer (score 2):

Does your code run before `HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState` event?
Is `SessionState http module` enabled? If thats disabled, your session would return null.

Comment: No but the ASP .NET page Inherits from a custom class which in turn inherits from system.web.ui.page. the code works on most of the other pages